# Indexing error in BFS algorithm of undirected graph

Tags: java, graph, breadth-first-search

```
class Solution {
 // Function to return Breadth First Traversal of given graph.
 public ArrayList<Integer> bfsOfGraph(int V, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj)     
 {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(0);
    
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];
    visited[0] = true;
    
    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        int v = q.poll();
        result.add(v);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> adjList = adj.get(v);
        for(int i : adjList) {
            if(!visited[i]) {
                visited[i] = true;
                q.add(i);    
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
 }      
}
```

Error:
[[image: ERROR Image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D8OX.png)

I am attempting bfs algorithm in undirected graph and it is showing
error of segmentation fault if anyone have any knowledge regarding the
concept please reply.

Comment: Add validation when V is negative or zero or adj is null/empty

Comment: the solution you provide is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation Faults happen in programs (such as the JVM) due to memory errors. Either the JVM has a bug in it that makes it try to use the wrong section of memory on the computer when its cranked up to use that much buffer space, or it tries to allocate 256M of memory and in the process, it uses more space than the computer gave it.
Make sure you update your JVM. Please let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: I am attempting this question on Geeks for geeks platform. This is the question link =https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/bfs-traversal-of-graph/1 . Please copy my code and see if you can help me here.

Comment: @LuvrajSingh- then that means that you are using more memory than they have allocated. Please optimize your code in terms of space. They have mentioned space complexity. See that you adhere to it. GFG is very strict in case of complexity and time limit.

Comment: thank you , the issue has been resolved.